# Changing <img src="XXX" />, js event when new image has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a photo gallery web page where a single `<img src="XXX" />` element's `src` is changed (on a click) with JavaScript to show the next image—a poor man's ajax I guess. Works great on faster connections when the new image appears almost immediately. Even if it takes a few seconds to load, every browser I've tested it on keeps the old image in place until the new one is completely loaded.

It's a little confusing waiting those few seconds on a slow connection, though, and I'm wondering if there's some JavaScript event that fires when the new image is done loading, allowing me to put a little *working...* animated gif or something up in the meantime.

I know I could use AJAX for real (I'm using jQuery already), but this is such a nice and simple solution. Besides this lag, is there any other reason I should stay away from this approach to changing images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up a handler on the "load" event.

```
$('img.whatever')
  .load(function() { /* do stuff */ })
  .attr('src', newURL);
```

<s>Actually I guess you'd want to do this with "live()":</s>

```
$('img.reloadable').live('load', function() { $(this).show(); });
// ...
$('img#someId').hide().attr('src', newURL);
```

*edit* — whoa, where did that year go?  Well, it turns out that one problem with that "live" approach I typed in way back when is that the "load" event **does not bubble**.  Now what you can do, however, is leverage the way that "Image" objects (as opposed to `<img>` DOM elements) behave. Basically, the function that changes the URL can use an "Image" element as the place to keep the handler. The code that *changes* the actual "src" attribute of the *real* `<img>` tag would then also update the "src" of the "Image" object instance. The browser will only really load the image once (assuming cache control is all cool), but the browser will still call the "onload" handler of the "Image":

```
(function() {
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    // code to run when image loads from server 
  };

  $('#hypotheticalButton').click(function() {
    $('#imgToUpdate').attr('src', newURL);
    imageObj.src = newURL;
  });
})();
```

Comment: thanks, this is it.  To be real clear for anyone else:  When `src="xxx"` is changed with js, `$.load()` fires AFTER the new image is finished loading.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. See sample: http://jsfiddle.net/fGmbN/  The alert is never displayed.

Comment: hmm ... @Tauren well let me play with it and see if I can figure out what's up.

Comment: @Tauren ah -- "load" doesn't bubble, it appears. Thus if you're trying to use "live" or "delegate", things are probably not going to work (maybe in some browsers, but maybe not).  I'll update the answer; thanks, and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thanks for the solution and description of why it wasn't working!

Answer (score 0):

You just just preload the images with jQuery so that way when the user clicks, the next image is already loaded and there shouldn't be a delay...that is unless the user goes to your page, and starts clicking on the image before they are loaded.

http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript

Comment: yeah I considered this but there's going to about 100 full-size images waiting to be loaded, and most people won't be looking at all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slideimg = $('#slideimage');
slideimg.click(function(){
    var img = new Image();
    var url = 'url_to_next_image.jpg';
    $(img).bind('load',function(){
        $('#loading').hide();
        slideimg.attr('src',url);
    }).attr('src',url);
    $('#loading').show();
});
```

This should work even with IE's crazy cache handling.

Comment: The only trouble with this is that it'll bind a new load handler on each click.